# 'Action' column of Visio document shapesheet won't retain "CALLTHIS(...,,)"

Tags: action, visio, shapesheet

I wish to add an option which runs a macro to a Visio document's context menu.  To do this, I have added a row to the Actions section of its shapesheet, with "Do X" in the Menu column.  I can now see this option in the context menu when I right-click on the diagram.  I tried adding '=CALLTHIS("ThisDcument.Test",,)' (without the single quotes) to the Action column, to run a public sub of that name in ThisDocument, but it won't persist - when I tab on from the column, its value reverts to 0.

I'm sorry if I'm missing the obvious, but can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to correct it?

Comment: Does the VALUE revert to 0, or does the FORMULA revert to 0? When you select the cell, does the Formula Bar display the proper formula? If so, there's no problem:`CALLTHIS()` evaluates to 0. You might also need to move `Test` to a Module, I seem to recall macros placed in `ThisDocument` not being accessible from `CALLTHIS()`

Answer (score 1):

Please check correct syntax
[image: Mistake]

Your sub-routine in VBA-code must have [Shape reference](https://bvisual.net/2021/02/22/using-the-callthis-function-in-visio/) like
`Sub test(sh As Shape)`